# CentOS Server won't reboot when issuing reboot command

Tags: linux, centos, runlevel

CentOS 5.x

Hi all,

For some reason, my CentOS server didn't want to reboot after I issued the **reboot** and **shutdown -r now** commands.  All I saw in the /var/log/messages logs were:

> Aug 25 13:34:32 voltage-out
>   shutdown[1784]: shutting down for
>   system reboot
>
> Aug 25 13:34:33 voltage-out init:
>   Switching to runlevel: 6

What would cause this? A hung process?  How can I best troubleshoot this if it comes up in the future?

-M

Comment: Does the command `init 6` work?

Comment: @kenny.r didn't try that.  I'll keep that in mind though.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should perform a `ps aux` to see if any of the shutdown scripts are hung waiting for a process to finish. It should look something like this:

```
/etc/rc6.d/K##procname
```

You can try manually issuing a `kill` command for that hung script. Strange though, since there's a timeout set on the scripts where it will force a `-KILL` signal to any leftover process.

Also, what's the uptime of the server/box? I've experienced an issue in the past where a box that has an uptime of over a year refuses to shut down. In that case, I've killed each process manually, run `sync` several times to flush all data to disk and forced a reboot (power cycle).

Comment: thanks for the tip.  That's exactly what I wanted to know. Uptime was over 300+ days

Comment: I'm having a similar problem.  But once it gets to this point, I don't have a console to check `ps aux`.  Any suggestion?